# Calling a Ajax function inside a Signalr Core

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, signalr

Hi Guys I just want to ask on how to call an Ajax function inside of signalR Core. Here is my sample code.

BTW I'm using asp.net core 2.2

This is my SignalR Code. Which will call the Ajax function "LoadTruckQueue". When a user click a button which has and id of #sendButton.

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/TruckHub").build();

connection.on('CallLoadTruckQueue', function (actionMessage) {
if(actionMessage != null){
   LoadTruckQueue();
}
});
connection.start().then(function () {
    console.log("Connected")
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
$(document).on('click', "#sendButton", function () {
    var actionMessage = document.getElementById("sendButton").value;
    connection.invoke("CallFunction", actionMessage).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
});
```

Then this is my TruckHub class which has a async Task of CallFunction which will call the CallLoadTruckQueue and has a string parameter of actionMessage.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web_UI.Hubs
{
    public class TruckHub : Hub
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task CallFunction(string actionMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("CallLoadTruckQueue", actionMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then this is my Ajax function called LoadTruckQueue

```
function LoadTruckQueue() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "/Truck/GetNewTrucks",
    }).done(function (data, statusText, xhdr) {
        $("#divTransaction").html(data);
    }).fail(function (xhdr, statusText, errorText) {

        let errorHeader = "System Error!";
        let errorBody = "List of Trucks cannot be loaded.\nPlease contact your 
        administrator";

        //function calling to display the Error Message
        DisplayErrorModal(errorHeader, errorBody);
    });

}
```

Well I'm not sure of the if I need to implement a asynx/await or promise call back when calling the Ajax Function. Since the LoadTruckQueue() function is calling my route /Truck/GetNewTrucks in controller which is in async/await. Thank you so much for those will give time and effort to address and help my issue/error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your SignalR JS client would make additional HTTP request to a backend service to get "TruckQueue" related data by calling `jQuery.ajax()` method to perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request while the SignalR JS client receive a specific message, which is ok.

On the other hand, if possible, you can implement data access logic of querying "TruckQueue" related data in a generic class separately, then you can reuse/consume that generic class method(s) in your hub method(s) directly, which would not require making additional HTTP request to (external) backend service from SignalR JS client side.

Comment: Hi Fei Thanks for answering my query. I have already find a solution. I just tried outside of the box solution by adding a delay seconds (3sec) in js function when the connection.on() in my signalr is triggered, by this my the socket connection on my signalr will give some buy time to get the asynchronous call to my Ajax function which is the LoadTruckQueue().